# Is Heart of Irons III played online regularly somewhere?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

Grand strategy games is a genre that I like very much but that it is difficult to play online. Is there any site where HoI fans gather to comment and play the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to register on the official HoI3 forums, and browse [this subforum](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=433) where people announce for multiplayer games (by region, etc).

I hooked up quite a good MP game with a couple of guys in my region a while back. Playing as France, I sadly got my ass handed to me ;)

Comment: I should also point out that HoI3 multiplayer doesn't have "servers" is the usual sense. One player acts as Host, the rest connect as Clients. There is a matchmaking metaserver provided by the publisher to provide chat and easier connection to games.